# Shared folder between two Web Servers

Tags: nginx, tomcat, web, directory

I'm running two webservers in a single host. One of them is a Tomcat running in a reverse proxy configuration. The front webserver is a nginx that proxies request to the Tomcat.

So far, is working ok.

A location in a domain, let's say domain.com/photos is server by Tomcat. I'd like the photos to be server by nginx. The files are stored in a folder, but the files are written by Tomcat application and the files end up with owner tomcat and group tomcat.

The nginx process is running in www-data group, so it cannot retrieve the files.

How can I accomplish that the the webservers runs under the same group?
Is a good practice to use newgrp before starting the webservers, so both runs under the same group?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered just adding your nginx user to the tomcat group? Seems like an easy solution...